# Can run but can't package maven spring-boot project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a dependency from another project and it's included in pom.xml. IntelliJ IDEA can run this project but can't package it in a jar file. I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mrpin/IdeaProjects/TanksOnline/Client/src/main/java/ru/urfu/Client/MyStompSessionHandler.java:[9,42] package ru.urfu.Server.GameLogic.GameBoard does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mrpin/IdeaProjects/TanksOnline/Client/src/main/java/ru/urfu/Client/MyStompSessionHandler.java:[10,42] package ru.urfu.Server.GameLogic.GameBoard does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mrpin/IdeaProjects/TanksOnline/Client/src/main/java/ru/urfu/Client/MyStompSessionHandler.java:[11,42] package ru.urfu.Server.GameLogic.GameBoard does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mrpin/IdeaProjects/TanksOnline/Client/src/main/java/ru/urfu/Client/MyStompSessionHandler.java:[12,42] package ru.urfu.Server.GameLogic.GameBoard does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mrpin/IdeaProjects/TanksOnline/Client/src/main/java/ru/urfu/Client/GameForm.java:[5,42] package ru.urfu.Server.GameLogic.GameBoard does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mrpin/IdeaProjects/TanksOnline/Client/src/main/java/ru/urfu/Client/GameForm.java:[6,42] package ru.urfu.Server.GameLogic.GameBoard does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mrpin/IdeaProjects/TanksOnline/Client/src/main/java/ru/urfu/Client/GameForm.java:[7,42] package ru.urfu.Server.GameLogic.GameBoard does not exist
```

Here's my pom.xml

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.urfu</groupId>
            <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And that's the structure of my project
[Server Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbAvl.png)
[Client Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp7nr.png)

tl;dr Client has dependency from somer Server projects. Maven can package Server but can't package Client (although can run).

Comment: First you have compile failures in your build than no jar file will be produced cause it wouldn't make sense...

Comment: @khmarbaise of course, I compile it before packaging. But I get the same error

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're packaging the server as a single-jer Spring Boot application, and then try to use this single-jar server application as a dependency in the client. A single-jar application is not mean't to be used as a library. Use a separate Maven module packaged as a library (i.e. not using the Spring Boot maen plugin), make the client dependant on this separate library module, and the server application too.

Comment: @JBNizet I get the idea. But I'm not sure how to do it. Can you give me an instruction?

Comment: I don't use Maven. If I had to, I would read the documentation and try something. That's what you should do.

Comment: @SimonRusinov please show the full pom file or best would be link to a project on Github/Bitbucket etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Here https://github.com/Pinkolik/TanksOnline/tree/master I would really appreciate your help

Comment: First remove the MANIFEST.MF from the server project. Spring Boot Project do not need manual MANIFEST.MF files. furthermore If you like to use server part as a dependency than you can't make it a spring boot application. After that make `mvn clean install` on the server and afterwards you can build Client module...

Comment: @khmarbaise Followed your instructions. Still same error :(